# Trouble understanding OEM HP Sensor CB781-80006 circuit

Tags: sensor, photosensor, cnc

I am having trouble understanding an OEM HP Sensor CB781-80006 circuit, I'm a beginner in electronics. Does anyone know to tell me what are the values ​​( VCC, GND, and outputs ) this sensor was removed from the old printer hp I want to use 3v in the input I will connect it with raspberry pi
Thank you

[image]

Comment: you show two different devices ... please post all available information about one of them ... include clear closeup photos, description of all visible markings

Comment: See this link: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=368884.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoder works 2.7 to 5.5V and has two collector output logic levels with built-in pullup resistors to Vcc.  Assuming it is using [this](https://html.alldatasheet.co.kr/html-pdf/748505/KODENSHI/KE-2-19/384/1/KE-2-19.html)

HP may have optimized the LED resistor for their supply. If that was 5V and you are using 3V then a somewhat smaller value is needed for the 1.6V LED (~20mA) in order to get quadrature square waves.

It appears to be a dual-channel rotary encoder somewhat like thumbwheel encoders in mice.

[image]